# MID function unexpected output

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Input in the excel B column
**O"PI-M99S_2000_K2_Published-UJM_CM1L_2000_M99S_**

Expected output : **CM1**

I used MID Function but that doesnt help me.

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CM",B2)),MID(B2,SEARCH("""",B2)+1,SEARCH("_",B2)-1-SEARCH("""",B2)),"")`

The output which i got:  **PI-M99S**

Can someone please guide in this where i am going wrong.

Comment: you are searching for the first `"` and the first `_` after that. Which is why you get what you get.  You need to change the search parameters.  Instead search for the `CM` and the first `_` after that.

Comment: Found the Logic, thanks for the spotting the mistake.
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CM1",A2)),"CM1","CM2")